# Replacing bathroom exhaust fan In Mobile home

Tags: wiring, installation, exhaust-fan, fans, bathroom-fixtures

so I’m not very handy and I need to replace my old exhaust fan in my bathroom of my mobile home. I’m having a hard time finding a new fan that will work with my current set up (vents straight up and out of my roof). I will attach a picture of the current fan.

I’m wondering if this is a fairly straightforward job or if I need to hire an electrician.

Any help is much appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Your question is entirely a matter of opinion and not for us to decide. Please revise to ask something more specific. See the [help] for tips.

Comment: You might want to consider hiring a handyman rather than an electrician. The main electrical issues will be working safely (making sure any electricity is shut off) and safely disconnecting the old wires and reconnecting the new wires. You don't want to end up with a poor connection that overheats and causes a fire or worse.

Comment: Interesting, @Armand, that you suggest a handyman, not an electrician, then go on to describe issues that an electrician should be expert at while a handyman might have only marginal skills...

Comment: @FreeMan Well, handyman is a catchall, so clearly a handyman experienced with properly using wire nuts and figuring out which breaker to shut off in addition to which screws to undo to remove the fan. Nothing complicated, but I get the impression the OP might not have the experience to do that safely. Similar to having a nurse bandage a wound rather than needing a doctor.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider is if the reason to replace the ventilation fan is due to:

1. The motor assembly and its bearings wearing out or becoming very loud
2. The fan housing is broken, rusted out or if the whole assembly has been damaged.

If you fall into the category of #1 above you should investigate replacement motor assemblies, which often come with the fan blade unit, are available in a large number of configurations (Amazon may be your friend here). This option is usually lower cost than replacing the whole fan unit. And if you purchase the correct motor/fan unit it should be relatively easy to install in your existing fan housing.

If you have to deal with a complete fan unit replacement then there is a bit more work involved. You will certainly be limited by the number of fan replacement units that vent out the top. Most units vent out the side or end. One suggestion is that it can really open up your number of available replacement options if you give up the need to find the exact same sized unit. A slightly larger unit can be usually accommodated with a small cutout adjustment in the ceiling hole. Obviously a smaller unit is not nearly as flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it. Have you already purchased a replacement? The most important thing is to make sure the power is off and check for dead. A proximity tester like this would do or one like it. [https://www.amazon.com/Non-Contact-Detector-Klein-Tools-NCVT1P/dp/B099SJ6469/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=Proximity+Tester&qid=1680640748&sr=8-7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B099SJ6469)

Perform a live-dead-live check. Which means check the tester on something you know is hot. Check your fan is dead and recheck your tester on a live source. It looks like a few screws to remove it and probably a couple of wire nuts to connect it. It already doesn't work, so if you get stuck on replacing it your not out anything and you can call a electrician or handyman. I think you will be successful and save yourself some money.

Rereading your question I see you're having trouble finding a replacement. I'm assuming that the motor failed? You should be able to get a replacement motor. They probably have a generic bathroom fan motor at your local hardware store.